# timestamp to datetime using dateadd is slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with timestamp column ts - linux timestamp (bigint), I want to convert it to datetime and I am using the following query:

Example:

```
select * from table1
where dateadd(S, ts, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')>'2019-09-01'
and  dateadd(S, ts, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')<'2019-09-10'
```

But `dateadd` is making the query very slow, is there other way to convert `timestamp` into `datetime` or a way to make the current query run faster?

Comment: Have you put an index on column `ts` ? BTW, you can also write this: `dateadd(year, ts, 1970);`

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there's nothing you can do. You use column `ts` in your statement, which is wrapped in a function, which would diable possible indexes on that column.

But you could rewrite this query, so the coulmn is not wrapped in any function:

```
where ts > datediff(s, '1970-01-01', '2019-09-01')
and ts < datediff(s, '1970-01-01', '2019-09-10')
```

Comment: This is a a better way to write the query, but it will only have a noticeable affect on performance if there is an index (or partitions) on `ts`.